# Create reusable blade block in Laravel4

Tags: laravel-4, laravel-blade

I want to create a reusable block in laravel blade template

I write pseudo code below, want to know how I can implement the scope

```
// app/views/layouts/code.blade.php
// the block I want to reuse
<pre>
    <code>
        // fill the content here
    </code>
</pre>
```

---

// app/views/myview.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.main') // set header, body, and footer block

@section ('content')
    @reuse_section('layouts.code')
       .......my code line 1
       .......my code line 2
    @endsection

    @reuse_section('layouts.code')
        .......my code line 1
        .......my code line 2
        .......my code line 3
    @endsection
 @endsection
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're best off creating a new `View::make()` call within your blade template.

```
// myview.blade.php
<?= View::make('partials.code', [
    'code' => 'my dynamic code content'
]); ?>
```

and your *code.blade.php* file takes the parameters just like:

```
// partials/code.blade.php
<pre>
    <code>
        {{ $code }}
    </code>
</pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can include view/block in template too. And pass variables, as well.

```
@extends('layouts.main') // set header, body, and footer block

@section ('content')
    @include('layouts.code', ['code'=>'some code'])
    @include('layouts.code', ['code'=>'some other code'])
 @endsection

 // layouts.code.blade.php
 <code>
    {{ $code }}
 </code>
```

Comment: I had tried this, but @include read only one line a time :(

Thanks for help :)))